# Configure Nginx static and Django site

Tags: django, linux, http, nginx, nginx-config

im trying to configure nginx to listen so that my subdomain "subdomain.exemple.com" listen to my  server site (Django), and that my  domain "exemple.com" to run some static site that doesnt require the server, so  I tried to configure this way:

installed cartbot and generated the ssl certificate

```
`sudo certbot certonly --manual -d example.com -d *.example.com --email your.email@example.com

cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
nano mydjangosite

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name django.exemple.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name django.exemple.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/exemple.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/exemple.com-0001/privkey.pem;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}`
```

after did I saved the file and did the nano staticsite

with this config

```
server {
    listen 7080;
    server_name exemple.com *.exemple.com;

    location / {
        root /home/jamelaumn/portfolio;
       index index.html;

    }
}
```

**just to that you know the port 7080 I chose randonly I dont know if it's alright**
I utilise linux and I dont know much if its okay to choose a random "port number" etc
after that I enabled  both sites
I did sudo ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
and I checked that both were enabled, I did nginx -t and it returned that everything was okay I went to my djangosite and started gunicorn but whenI accessed exemple.com insted of loading the staticsite it loaded the django site how do I fix it?like the django to only listen that subdomain and the domain exemple.com to only load the static site serverless

in nginx/sites-available there's a  default file I dont know if I have to change anythin but I will provide the configuration

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```